# Insert timestamp in SQLite stays null

Tags: android, sqlite, timestamp

I'm using the following code to insert a row with a timestamp column into a SQLite database:

```
ContentValues contentValues = new ContentValues();
contentValues.put(LAST_UPDATE, "15-02-2012 11:27:42");
database.insert(TABLE_NAME, null, contentValues );
```

When I check the table afterwards, the column with the timestamp (defined as `timestamp not null`) is always `null`. The other columns (not shown in the code sample) are ok. Any ideas?

Comment: I think the format for datetime should be `YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS` you are using `DD-MM-YYYY HH:MM:SS`. Try to change it a see if it works. Also.. you are settings `contentValues` but then using `initialValues` for the `INSERT`

Comment: Changing the date format doesn't change the result. The `initialValues` was a typo.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you should use the following date format in order to insert dates/times in SQLite:

```
DateFormat dateFormatISO8601 = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");
```

and retrieve in string as below:

```
String crntDate = dateFormatISO8601.format(new Date());
```

P.S. Make sure your column is of type `DATETIME`

Comment: I switched the column type to `datetime`, now it works. I really thought I had used `timestamp` succesfully before.

Comment: i guess timestamp has different format, but anyhow, good to know it helped you :)